# While executing the "yarn start" command "error Command failed with exit code 1."

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I tried the command `yarn start` for my react project

I am getting this error

```
yarn run v1.22.10
warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts start
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/code-frame'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\2021\Procare_UI\node_modules\react-dev-utils\typescriptFormatter.js:11:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How can I resolve this issue?